# How powerful do you think this invented power is?

Tags: world-of-darkness, homebrew, vampire-the-masquerade

I've created a new Discipline for Vampire: The Masquerade to make a really diehard boss. It's completely not for neonates, as it burns a lot of blood points per turn. The thing is, I don't know if it's too overpowered or if it would be OK for experienced characters.

Here it is!

### **True Vampire**

**Level 1: Soul Eater**

Not many Cainites know the power of human souls, but the ones who know of it first need to harvest the souls. With this power, the vampire can literally eat someone soul.

**System:** First of all, the Cainite needs to hunt his prey and then use 10 blood points to cover the prey in blood. Then, the vampire must drink the mortal's blood entirely, killing the human in the process. When this happens, the human and vampire make a contested Willpower roll, where the difficulty is the victim's Willpower. If the vampire fails the roll, the human soul escapes and the vampire's aura bears diablerie marks for 3 days. On a botch, the human soul seizes control of the vampire, and the vampire's "soul" will be condemned to remain in hell until the human dies. If the vampire absorbs a human soul, it can use it to prevent his final death, so for each soul it has another opportunity to escape from death.

**Level 2: Partial Blood Regeneration**

**System:** By spending 20 blood points, the vampire can regenerate one level of aggravated damage in a turn.

**Level 3: Blood Control**

**System:** For each success on a Manipulation + Occult roll (diff. 6), the Cainite absorbs 1 blood point from living beings around him.

**Level 4: Hell Dog**

Like a shapeshifter, the vampire can transform into a something similar to a hellhound, making the mortals flee from battle.

**System:** The vampire rolls Manipulation + Occult (diff. 8) and spends 15 blood points. It takes one turn to transform and it last 1 hour for each success. All supernatural entities will have to roll Courage with a difficulty of 10 - the Humanity of the caster or flee. Less humane vampires have more terrifying forms.

**Level 5: Complete Regeneration**

**System:** Spending 40 blood points, the vampire regenerates all damage. It takes two turns, and all witness will have to roll Courage at a difficulty of 8.

**Level 6: Corpse cloning**

**System:** Spending 10 blood points, the vampire can replicate himself. Each clone has one of the vampire's disciplines. The clone has no survival instinct and will fight until it dies. Killing the original vampire will cause the clones to die.

**Level 7: Soul Army**

**System:** Expending all of his absorbed souls, the Cainite releases them to fight his enemies. It takes three turns to complete this, and those who witness this would need to roll Courage at a difficulty of 9. A vampire in this state can fight but cannot use souls to prevent the final death. At any moment, he can reabsorb the souls, again, taking three turns to do so.

Comment: Oh, if someone like's it, it can use it just refering to me! It appears in a little "manual" that i've done. You can download the spanish  version in [link](http://noeselmastersonlosdados.blogspot.com.es/p/material-pdf.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is overpowered. But not because it's hard to deal with. Actually, in VtM player characters are not supposed to *encounter* creatures, who can use this discipline. Blood expenditure requirements (more than 10 bp per turn) limit this discipline to Antediluvians (and Cain himself), who are mythic god-like creatures mere awakening of whom means End of Times (Gehenna). And Antediluvians can do everything storyteller want them to do, no need to invent new disciplines for them.

I don't have a rulebook right now, but quick google gives a link to blood pool and related rules: http://reference.l2fury.com/index.php/Generation. And it looks like the part of rulebook I remember.

And please forgive me for some criticism, but maybe you should rethink your approach to VtM. This discipline looks like a thing from computer video game. In pen-and-paper VtM there is less emphasis on combat, especially long, enduring combat (and your discipline looks like it was meant just for that). Elders have other means to be dangerous and hard-to-kill. And usually there is little point in trying to kill them.

If you want an elusive adversary, who keeps appear before player's characters no matter how they tries to destroy it on every occasion, there are many vampiric powers for that. For example, Serpentis 5 render it's user immune to staking, Dominate 5 enable to possess mortals, Vicissitude provide means to change it's user appearance or shape others, while Vicissitude 5 gives means for escape, Protean 5 also gives means for escape, Obfuscate can hide vampire under an illusion, Chimerstry create complex and seemingly real illusions...

Even simple Vicissitude 2 + blood bond could give you a substitue for "cloning" (making thralls, who very much resemble their master).

But more terrifying enemy (and more in the spirit of the game) would be the one, whom player characters can't even reach and see face to face, because of his/her connections, allies, servants, resources and other acquired "conventional" powers.

Comment: Well, in this case, the npc that would use it is a complete combat npc, based on Alucard from Hellsing, and is a so action driven Story. And also is an Apocaliptic one, merging the Gehena with other apocalipse, so i have demons, werewolves, vampires, mages... And the demon part is...how can I say...so unpredictable? They seem that team work doesn't ment anything for them (for the players) and I need a monster they don't even know how to deal with.

Comment: @SliferDragon: Then you may be solving the wrong problem here.  We can advise you on how to make this Discipline balanced... but then it won't do what you want.  You'd be better asking about effective combat uses of the disciplines that already exist.  Obfuscate / Celerity / Protean / Dominate etc. already do some utterly nasty things if used right; you don't need a special uberdiscipline.

I'd recommend a new question about the underlying problem you're trying to solve. If the problem is that the party won't do team work in an action-style story, then ask about fostering team work.

Comment: To mimic Alucard one could introduce Tzimisce of 4-5 generation. In Dark Age clan novel Ventrue is depicted fight with such creature (Tzimisce, not Alucard) and it's interesting although they do not use any particularly advanced disciplines. But much more interesting and thematical would be Ravnos of 7, maybe 6 generation. Chimerstry could produce almost anything, including Alucard's tricks. And it would be a beautiful moment of personal horror for your players, when they understand that they where fighting illusions.

Answer (score 6):

### It's not all that great, actually.

The majority of the powers you describe serve one purpose: to keep the NPC alive and in the fight for a long period of time. Avoid death, heal some damage, feed quickly, heal all damage, make Doombots. None of these effects do anything but prolong combat. To do this, you need to spend dozens upon dozens of blood points — but those will be coming from other NPCs, since your players' characters are going to be something other than human — and rounds upon rounds of time. During which time, the PCs will be focusing fire on him to make him take damage faster than he can heal it. You're not making the fight more interesting; you're just extending it.

Thaumaturgy, Necromancy, Protean and Fortitude can accomplish 90% of what this power does and don't require a blood pool that reaches into the triple digits. I'd use them instead.